# Test Page Apache httpd on docs.domain.com

Tags: apache-2.4, redirect, test

I have a wordpress website server running on linux.
I have a issues when I enter docs.domain.com it opens a Test Page [Test Page pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiSWF.png) . So my target is when users enter https://docs.example.com to redirect them to https://example.com/example-documentation/ , can you help me ?
Best Regards

```
    [example conf.d]$ cat docs.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin office+web@example.com
    ServerName docs.example.com
    ServerAlias docs.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/brand/Documentation/new


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =docs.example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you googled `redirect apache`? Have you read Apache documentation, which frankly is *excellent*?

Comment: Yes, but I do not have a test environment :) I am a little bit coward to test the things on the production. I think iif I add this rule 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^docs\.example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/example-documentation/$1 [L,R=301]

Will do the things ?

Comment: Or if I modify the docs.conf file and add a "Redirect 301 /example-documentation https://docs.example.com" ?

Comment: <IfModule alias_module>
    #
    # Redirect: Allows you to tell clients about documents that used to
    # exist in your server's namespace, but do not anymore. The client
    # will make a new request for the document at its new location.
    # Example:
    # Redirect permanent /foo http://www.example.com/bar
What if I modify the httpd.conf and add Redirect permanent /example-documentation https://www.docs.example.com ?

Comment: Good chance to set up a test environment then. VirtualBox is free of charge, and allows you to spin up a VM with Apache.

Comment: Okay, just asked if someone experienced this and know what to do exactly :) Thanks in advance

Comment: Tried a lot of things from the documentation but it is not working  :(